# Android USB Library

Tags: java, android, usb, arduino, adk

i`m trying to make an Arduino ADK + Android, and for this i have to use a USB library from android. 
The library is com.android.future.usb, and i import com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory, and com.android.future.usb.UsbManager.
I compile to my android 2.3.6 (Galaxy ACE), but the app stops because this error:

> 06-11 23:19:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1842): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   06-11 23:19:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.android.future.usb.UsbManager
>   06-11 23:19:02.359: E/AndroidRuntime(1842):   at
>   com.example.arduinoblinkled.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)

Comment: How did you import Android USB library into your Android tool? It seems that your Android project classpath settings does not include the library reference.

Comment: "import com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory;
import com.android.future.usb.UsbManager;"

Comment: No, I mean the physical location of the library jar file: how did you include it as part of your project's Android Library References setup?

Comment: Try to include the jar file into the default "libs" folders created by any Android project or add it into the Project Build Path from Android IDE. Refresh your project after that to reflect new changes.

Comment: The jar file its the "usb.jar" that is in google api's 10?

Comment: @eee, i added the usb.jar to libs, and add to build path, but nothing changes. :s

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Galaxy ACE is a device that does not support AOA. Your getting the NoClassDefFoundError because it's simply not on your device.